# Where are the options "template" and "current_theme" derived from

Tags: theme-development

My theme is in a folder called "mytheme" and the "Theme Name" in the style.css is "My Theme".

From that, I'm guessing that the option "template" in the options table is a reference to the folder, not the "Theme Name".

I'm asking because I want to be sure that the value I should pass to switch_theme() is a reference to the foldername mytheme, not the theme name "My Theme" ?

```
switch_theme('mytheme', 'style.css')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'r right. The template-tag is based on your directory name. Same goes for a child-theme, which has a base theme as parent.

Check out the search_theme_directories() function for more information.

Comment: thanks, just wanted validation of my assumptions there. I think what was unclear to me is when the docs refer to "Theme Name", they usually are referring to the "folder name", not the "Theme Name" specified in style.css

Comment: @ScottB You're welcome. ;) The docs are sometimes a bit confusing. I would recommend to read through the sourcecode. Just use a good IDE with declaration support, so you can jump around the defined funtions and see what they are doing in the background.